C: Hd volume serial number getting extremely slow
I have to read the C# volume serial number (the one provided when typing dir in a cmd prompt).
That has always worked but today it is extremely slow.

[01.07.2024 12:54:35.415] I GetHdSerialString START


[01.07.2024 12:55:41.936] I GetHdSerialString END

so like more than one minute to get it.
The routine is the following
public static string GetHdSerialString()
{
    try
    {
        WriteNLog("GetHdSerialString START ", eLogLevel.Info);
        using ManagementClass mangnmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk");
        using ManagementObjectCollection mcol = mangnmt.GetInstances();
        string result = "";
        foreach (ManagementObject strt in mcol.Cast<ManagementObject>())
        {
            result += Convert.ToString(strt["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
            break; //mi interessa solo il primo
        }

        result = result.Insert(4, "-");
        WriteNLog("GetHdSerialString END ", eLogLevel.Info);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        WriteNLog("GetHdSerialString exc:" + exc.Message, eLogLevel.Error);
        return String.Empty;
    }
}

Here is the point where it takes so long

Can anyone tell me why all of a sudden it takes so long and how to fix it?
I also tried other ways or retrieving that data but couldn't find any.
Thanks
Patrick

I can't reproduce this. I tried the nuget package System.Management with version 8.0.0 and 9.0.0-preview.5.24306.7. Both times your function finished within a second or so. So I guess it's not a library problem, but maybe something hardware/os/driver related?

Thank you so much for your help. I tried some hw or driver causes but that was not the case. So I thought about the antivirus and without it that worked! Not sure why the antivirus is interfering with the hw management but as a matter of fact without it starting is immediate, with it it takes ages. So thank you! Perhaps you might want to put you comment as an answer for you put me on the right track with it

It's ok to answer your own question if you found a solution :)

Actually the user  "Good Night Nerd Pride" put me on the right track. As written in the comment above I tried some hw or driver causes but that was not the case. So I thought about the antivirus and without it that worked! Not sure why the antivirus is interfering with the hw management but as a matter of fact without it starting is immediate, with it it takes ages.
